# Upload file to form and submit using REST api

Tags: ios, swift, forms, http, post

My Issue is that I need to upload a file to a server (using swift and REST) which will then be uploaded to a device. On the server I have a form (html,js) which can handle the upload to the device by sending the file in chunks using POST requests. So it seems I have two options.

1) I can skip the form altogether and post directly to the device, but I would have to handle slicing the file, and sending the data in chunks on the client side in swift, or

2) I can somehow use REST apis to upload the file to the input in the form, and then again use REST to submit the form allowing the server to handle the transaction between the device.

I can handle option 1 if 2 isn't possible, but I'm really hoping option 2 is possible, and I have very little experience in this neighborhood.

Here is the form:

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//jsSrc"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="upgrade_panel">
            <input class="file_selector" type="file" name="fileImage" id="firmware_image"></input>
            <button class= "upgrade_button" type="button" id="upgradeButton" onclick="send_file_in_chunks()" >Start upgrade</button>
    </div>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function send_file_in_chunks(){
    var file = document.getElementById("firmware").files[0];
    var tmp = file.name.split(".");
    var app_index = tmp[1];
    var upgrade_chunk_url_with_query;
    var current_pos = 0;
    var size = file.size;
    var expected_md5 = //expected_md5

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    upgrade_chunk_url_with_query = "upgrade_chunk.html" + "?" + "offset=" + current_pos + "&" + "filesize=" + size + "&" + "appindex=" + app_index + "&" + "expected_md5=" + expected_md5;
    xhr.open('POST', upgrade_chunk_url_with_query , true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange= send_function;

    function send_function() {
        if ( (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) ) {
            //Send some data
        } else {
        if ( (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status== 0) ) {
            //Re-send some data
        }
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain why "I would have to handle slicing the file", in particulat why th efile must be sliced?

Comment: My expertise is mainly on the software side of things, but the impression I get is I don't think that the device can handle large data transfers at once, and since the file is pretty big if the connection is interrupted we won't have to re-send the whole file if we send it in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

So, how large is "large data"? Files of 100MB are not unreasonable for current devices, 10MB or less is not large at all.

Slicing is sometimes done so that if the transmission is interrupted it can be resumed, AWS is an example.

If the data is to large to fully fit in memory consider using streaming to a file.

Comment: The file is most likely smaller than 10MB (haven't gotten my hands on it yet), but another reason we have to use chunking is because we are restricted in changing the code on the device that will be accepting the transfer and that code is only setup to handle chunks of 1024 bytes at a time unfortunately.

Comment: So sad. More code, more complexity: more bugs, less security.